# Read file using FileDialog and save to the List<>

Tags: c#

I am trying to read text file and store the information into the List<>.

So far, I managed to read strings off the file and split it, but having trouble storing the information onto the List<>. Perhaps I am trying to do too many things under one function.

```
using System.IO;

private void openFileDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
            using (FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(myOpenFileDialog.FileName))
            {

                StreamReader reader;
                reader = new StreamReader(fStream);
                string line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] playerInfo = line.Split(';');
                    int ID = int.Parse(playerInfo[0]);
                    string firstName = playerInfo[1];
                    string lastName = playerInfo[2];
                    DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(playerInfo[3]);
                    List<Player> players = new List<Player>
                    players.add(new Player(id, firstName, lastName, dob);
                }

            }
        }
```

When I check with MessageBox.Show, it comes out with 0 for the amount of lines I have in the file...
Perhaps my list.add code is in wrong place.
Thank you for your help and your time

Comment: Move `List<Player> players = new List<Player>;` to above the `while` loop, not inside it.

Comment: Yep, Basically each loop through your `while` loop you're creating a new `List<Player` and then at the end of each loop that list gets discarded. It's a scope issue.

Comment: Don't get in the habit of using messagebox.show to debug your code. Attach a debugger to it. It will give you significantly more data to work with to troubleshoot your code. Oh and you need a try catch in here big time.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Thank you for the tips. I am new to the programme and am finding my ways through. What would be the best way to attach debugger?

Comment: Visual studio is the main IDE for C# related development, although VSCode is a great lightweight one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new List every time you're iterating over a new line, that's probably why you're not getting the correct amount of lines.

I also saw you have a few sintax errors in your code, I'll asume that you didn't copy/paste the code directly from the source and that's the reason of those errors (The Add method is in uppercase, and you missed the parentheses when initializing the List)

The working code would be like this:

```cs
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    string[] playerInfo = line.Split(';');
    int ID = int.Parse(playerInfo[0]);
    string firstName = playerInfo[1];
    string lastName = playerInfo[2];
    DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(playerInfo[3]);
    players.Add(new Player(id, firstName, lastName, dob);
}
```

If you want to have access to the list more globally you could do it this way:
Let's assume your class name is Sample:

```cs
public class Sample {
    // Declare the list as a private field
    private List<Player> players;

    // Constructor - Creates the List instance
    public Sample() {
        players = new List<Player>();
    }

    private void openFileDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        players.Clear(); //Clears the list
        if (myOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
        using (FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(myOpenFileDialog.FileName)) {
            StreamReader reader;
            reader = new StreamReader(fStream);
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                string[] playerInfo = line.Split(';');
                int ID = int.Parse(playerInfo[0]);
                string firstName = playerInfo[1];
                string lastName = playerInfo[2];
                DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(playerInfo[3]);
                players.Add(new Player(id, firstName, lastName, dob);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Declaring the list this way you'll be able to get the values of the list from other methods inside the same class.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I wrote the code on the site instead of copy and paste... 
I see the problem, when I view the list inside the while loop, it shows but when I want to see it outside the loop, it's empty again. Is there any ways of making the list global?

Comment: Outside the loop the list should still be full, since you've not applied any logic to clear the list. However maybe you're trying to read the list out of its scope. The list is declared inside the Using(FileStream ... { 

  }
So you'll only be able to use the list inside of that using. You're probably trying to get the values from the list outside of that scope and that's the error. You'll need to have the list as a field or o property in order to have it globally, I'll edit my answer to show you how.